# I can't access method parameter in the a method Python

Tags: python, methods, parameters

I'm writing an extension for sklearn preprocessing. I faced a peculiar situation as I seems cannot access my method attribute in part of code but in other part can. Here is what I mean:

```
class OneHotEncoder(preprocessing.OneHotEncoder):
    def __init__(self, n_values=None, categorical_features=None,
                 categories=None, drop=None, sparse=True, dtype=np.float64,
                 handle_unknown='error'):
        super().__init__(n_values, categorical_features, categories, drop, sparse, dtype, handle_unknown)

    def encode(self, X, columns, inplace: bool = False):
        """Encode categorical features as a pandas dataframe.

        Parameters
        ----------
        X : pandas dataframe.
        columns : a list of str.
            Indict which columns you wish to encode.
        inplace : bool, default False
            If True, do operation inplace and return None.

        Return
        ----------
        encoded_X : One-hot encoded dataframe if inplac=False
        """
        new_data = X.copy()
        if not isinstance(columns, collections.Sequence):
            raise TypeError("Input must be a sequence-like parameter 'columns'")
        if len(columns) == 0:
            raise ValueError("Input must not be empty parameter 'columns'")
        if isinstance(X, pd.DataFrame):
            self.fit(new_data)
            init_categories = self.categories_.copy()
            for column in columns:
                encoded_n_array = super().fit_transform(new_data.loc[:, column].to_frame()).astype(self.dtype).toarray()
                num_categories = len(self.categories_[0])
                if self.drop == 'first':
                    # If only one category is present, the feature will be dropped entirely.
                    if num_categories != 1:
                        num_categories = len(self.categories_[0]) - 1
                        col_names = np.char.add(np.repeat(column + '_', num_categories), self.categories_[0][1:])
                    else:
                        continue
                elif self.drop == 'if_binary' and num_categories == 2:
                    col_names = np.array([column + '' + self.categories_[0][1]])
                else:
                    col_names = np.char.add(np.repeat(column + '_', num_categories), self.categories_[0])
                encoded_df = pd.DataFrame(encoded_n_array, columns=col_names)
                new_data = pd.concat([new_data, encoded_df], axis=1)
                new_data = new_data.drop(columns=column)
            self.categories_ = init_categories
            if inplace:
                X = new_data       ################### Here is the problem. I can't access to X
            else:
                return new_data
        else:
            raise TypeError("Input must be a DataFrame parameter 'X'")
```

I indicted the problematic part. PyCharm shows me the following inspection:

> Variable in function should be lowercase
> Inspection info: This inspection checks the PEP8 naming conventions.
> See PEP 8 for more details.
> Local variable 'X' value is not used
> Inspection info: This inspection highlights local variables,parameters or local functions unused in scope.

Apparently I'm making a new variable named X instead of referencing X parameter. It's not an IDE inspection problem. I don't know what I did wrong. Why I can't reference X parameter not in the beginning of the method I can?

Comment: `X = new_data` doesn't actually do anything in place. It just rebinds the `X` local variable. It has no effect whatsoever on the code that called this method.

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean. The idea here is change input X after new_data been modified. As what inplace does. Modify input in place. How can i change it? Plus I still don't get why I can't even reference X here